# MySQL : Syntax error creating new trigger with Inner Join

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

So I am trying to create a trigger but I am getting a syntax error:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_total_play_time AFTER INSERT ON play_log
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE
            user u
        INNER JOIN
            play_log lp
        ON u.id = lp.user_id
        SET u.total_listened_seconds = u.total_listened_seconds + NEW.play_time
           WHERE u.id = NEW.user_id;
    END;
```

I cannot seem to understand why would there be an error? It says that the error is on the line where the **WHERE u.id = NEW.user_id;** is but if I remove it then it says that it is on the line before that.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need the join at all?  Just use `NEW`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_total_play_time AFTER INSERT ON play_log
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE user u
           SET u.total_listened_seconds = u.total_listened_seconds + NEW.play_time
           WHERE u.id = NEW.user_id;
    END;
```